# How to close calendar popup after clicking on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, datetimepicker

How can I hide the calendar after a date is selected? I am using [Date-time-picker by DanyelYKPan](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker).

Is there a specific function that I can use? My code below

```
 <div class="col-3">
  <div class="form-group calenderForm calenderForm1">
   <label for="templateName">REPAIR DATE (FROM)</label>
    <owl-date-time name="repairDateFrom"
     [(ngModel)]="repairDateFrom" 
     [max]="max"
     [type]="'calendar'"
     [dateFormat]="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
     [placeHolder]="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
    ></owl-date-time>
  <div class="error-message-block"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="repairDateFrom" id = "repairDateFrom" value="
  {{repairDateFrom | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" (click)="closeDatePopUp()"/>
  </div>
 </div>
```

From top of the code  through picker plugin component call will goes to below function.

```
    DateTimePickerComponent.prototype.updateFormattedValue = function () {
    var formattedValue = '';
    if (this.value) {
        var d = new Date();

        if (this.isSingleSelection()) {
            this.value = this.value.setHours(d.getHours(), d.getMinutes());
            formattedValue = date_fns_1.format(this.value, this.dateFormat, 
            { locale: this.locale.dateFns });
            $('.owl-calendar-wrapper').on('click',function(){
                $('.owl-dateTime-dialog').hide();
            });
        }}}
```

I tried with above code it will works only one time after clicking on date field second time date popup will not come.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would use the mechanism of [Parent call of @ViewChild](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild) described in the angular Component Interaction page.

1 - import the DateTimePickerComponent

```
import  { DateTimePickerComponent } from "ng-pick-datetime/picker.component"
```

2- Refer it to ViewChild and assign a variable name:

```
@ViewChild(DateTimePickerComponent) picker: DateTimePickerComponent;
```

3- Now you can access all non private attribute/method described here: https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker/blob/master/src/picker.component.ts by `this.picker`

For hiding the calendar you can set the `dialogVisible` to `false`:

```
this.picker.dialogVisible = false
```

Now time to detect the click event in our calendar. The simplest way is to use (ngModelChange) event.

```
<owl-date-time
  [(ngModel)]="repairDateFrom" name="repairDateFrom" 
  (ngModelChange)="onDateChange()"
  [type]="'calendar'"
  [dateFormat]="'YYYY-MM-DD'"
></owl-date-time>
```

And in our component :

```
onDateChange() {
    this.picker.dialogVisible = false;
}
```